# Ember Simple Auth - How To Update The Stored Token

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

On each request my application makes, a token is returned inside the response.
This is the token that needs to be used for the next request.

This works (partially). When I refresh the App it runs the restore function but uses the wrong token.

```
    var Parent = this;

    Ember.$(document).ajaxComplete(function(Event, Response) {

        Parent.session.content.Token = Response.responseJSON.Token;

    });
```

It would seem that the above code updates the token in memory but not in the store which the authenticator uses upon "restoring" the session using the restore function.

How can I update the token in the localStorage to use this token for all requests/re-validations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Ember's `set` method so the session can detect that the Token has changed: `session.set('token', Response.responseJSON.Token);`.